# Query the database where used for loops

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a problem calling the database where I used for loops.

database query 1

```
SELECT id,qtyslot FROM rack WHERE theid = '1'
```

Eg `id = 2`
and `qtyslot = 12`

We create for loops

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++) {
```

Here I call the database with the identity of the slot varies
1 or 2,4 (with comma from 2 to 4 slots) and etc.

HOW CAN SELECT

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE idrack = '2' AND slot"......." // $x
```

The database structure as follow.

```
-----------------------
| id | slot    | name |
-----------------------
| 1  |  1      | name |
-----------------------
| 2  |  2,4    | name | --> How to define this with the above loop ($x)
-----------------------
| 3  |  5,6    | name | --> How to define this with the above loop ($x)
-----------------------
| 4  |  7      | name |
-----------------------
```

And the result like this in table

```
-----------------------------------------
| loop qtyslot | In slot        | remark |
-----------------------------------------
| 1            | name slot 1    | remark |
-----------------------------------------
| 2            |                |        |
---------------|                |        |
| 3            | Name slot 2,4  | remark |
---------------|                |        |
| 4            |                |        |
-----------------------------------------
| 5            |   Name in      |        |
---------------|    slot 5,6    | remark|
| 6            |                |        |
------------------------------------------
etc up to 12
```

Can anyone help me.

Comment: first of all use `strpos` to detect if we have a comma in the string, Then `explode`. This will be done if we have a comma of course. else proceed with normal iteration. OR you can use mysql's `IN` operator and then `implode`

Comment: Thanks @Akin. But for the slot column it is the value from - to, not the default value. Example that 2.4 is located on LOOP 2, LOOP 3 and LOOP 4. But part of the slot is only 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function in mysql.
Try This :

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE idrack = '2' AND $x BETWEEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(slot, ',', 1) and SUBSTRING_INDEX(slot, ',', -1)
```

Comment: But for the slot column it is the value from - to, not the default value. For example 2.4 it is slot 2, 3 and 4. And the result will be like the table above, for example where slot 2.4 will be joined from loop 2,3 and 4.
Thank you for your attention

Comment: I've tried and the results are appropriate. Thank you very much. It's very petrified once. Thanks again. But if you do not mind please help me how to make the name in slot spaced, if using table then <td> ordered rowspan = 3 of this result 2.4 (3 slots). Please help. Like the table above.

Comment: Or something like @Ahmed Ginani, how to find specify a number of slots 2,4 with id = 1 ? Later the result is 3 because the number of slots 2,3 and 4 are 3 slots . This is what I really can not. Please help